# Best options for archive library for Android

Tags: android

I'm creating an Android app that will handle collections of image files.

I'm looking for an archive format (and library) similar to .zip or .tar that meets these requirements:

1. Open source
2. Allows extraction of a single file without extracting
   all files
3. Capable of containing image and text (probably json) files

I'm looking for something that is well supported on Android.  Something that works for Android and IOS would be a plus.

Answer (score 1):

What about [Gzip](https://www.gnu.org/software/gzip/)? Open source and it has [native support](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.html) on Android.

For iPhone, you could use the [ZipArchive](https://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/) library, though it may also have native support. (Search the SDK, I don't know how!)

Comment: As of 2022, [zip](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/InflaterInputStream) is natively supported as well.